# Как в PHP получить представление числа с плавающей точкой до заданной точности?

Tags: php

Когда в PHP используются числа с плавающей точкой, то их реальное представление может отличать от того, что выводится. Даже отладочные функции не могут прояснить в чём дело, например:

```
$x = 8 - 6.4;  // равно  1.6
$y = 1.6;
var_dump($x);  // вернёт 1.6
var_dump($y);  // вернёт 1.6
var_dump($x === $y); // FALSE!!!
var_dump(round($x,2) == round($y,2)); // TRUE, после округления
```

Проверка через var_dump() вводит в заблуждения. Хотя на самом деле всё дело в реальном представлении числа. Как отобразить переменные с плавающей точкой $x и $y с произвольной точностью, т.е:

```
1.60000000 <= $x
1.59999999 <= $y
```

**Существует ли такая возможность?**

Answer (score 0):

нашёл такое решение

```
echo number_format( $x, 20, ".", "" ); echo "\n";
echo number_format( $y, 20, ".", "" ); echo "\n";
```

воспользовался данной функцией и получил результат:

```
1.59999999999999964473
1.60000000000000008882
```

далее разбираюсь с особенностями вычислений чисел со знаками..

и ещё функция var_export( ), которое позволяет получить полное строковое представление переменной. В этом случае можно получить число со знаком до того разряда, дальше, которого вычисление дробной части не имеет смысла:

```
echo var_export($x); echo "\n"; // 1.5999999999999996447286321199499070644378662109375
echo var_export($y); echo "\n"; // 1.600000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625
```

Comment: Представление чисел с плавающей точкой в PHP позволяет получить гарантированно 14 значащих цифр. Остальное артефакты. Почитайте дополнительно IEEE 754